# Fifth differentiation of a function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let a function y= $x/(x^2-1)$

And we have to find $y^{\left(\mathtt{V}\right)}(0) $

I wrote $y= {1\over 2}\left[{1\over (x-1)} + {1\over (x+1)}\right]$

But  I am now stuck please help me to proceed .

Comment: So you have $y = \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{1}{x-1}+\frac{1}{x+1} \right)$, fine.  Do you know how to take derivatives of $\frac{1}{x^k}$?  Taking derivatives of $\frac{1}{(x-1)^k}$ and $\frac{1}{(x+1)^k}$ is just like that.

Comment: Cant you do the layman's way?

Comment: You can find the Maclaurin expansion without partial fractions in this case, for our expression is equal to $-x(1+x^2+x^4+\cdots)$.

Comment: @BrianTung i don't know how to do that

Comment: Well, $\frac{1}{x^k}$ is the same thing as $x^{-k}$, and you can apply your usual rule for differentiating a power of $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am just expanding on the comments and previous answer hopefully explaining a bit more explicitly:

let us take the function $f(x) = x^{-k}$
$$ f^{'} = -kx^{-k-1}\\
 f^{''} = (-1)^2k(k+1)x^{-k-2}\\
f^{'''} = (-1)^3k(k+1)(k+2)x^{-k-3}\\\vdots\\
f^{'''''} = -k(k+1)(k+2)\cdots(k+4)x^{-k-5}$$

The same holds for another such $f$ say $f(x)=(x+n)^{-k}$ Your partial fraction expansion makes things easier since thats corresponds to $n=\pm1$ and $k=1$ hence applying the observations you can check to see the result is:
$$ \frac{d^5}{dx^5}\left\lbrace \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{1}{x-1} + \frac{1}{x+1}\right)\right\rbrace =
\frac{5!}{2}\left( \frac{1}{(x-1)^{6}} + \frac{1}{(x+1)^{6}}\right)$$
Which may be cleaned up in the rational form if you wanted to

Answer (score 1):

What are some properties of the derivative "operator?"

**Hint**:
$\left(f+g\right)^{'}= f^{'}+g^{'}$

Of course doing it this way is somewhat "primitive." Maybe someone else could chime in on a more elegant solution!